# How to show all months in google chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm creating a monthly sale chart by using Google chart. I want to display all months in the chart even if the sale doesn't exist. For example, if there is no sale made in February, then it should show the value of 0

basically, the month should still show, but the value should be zero.

Here is what I achieved so far

invoice_order table

```
order_id | order_date | order_total_amount
1        | 2021-01-01 | 1000
2        | 2021-03-01 | 2000
```

The above table would return the sale of January and March and shows those months in the chart but I want to also show February with the value of 0 in the chart. Basically, all months need to shows up in the chart regardless of the sale. I hope you got an idea!

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Monthly', 'Sales'],
          <?php 
          $select_sale = "select date_format(order_date,'%M'), sum(order_total_amount) from invoice_order group by year(order_date),month(order_date) order by year(order_date),month(order_date)";
          $select_sale_query = mysqli_query($connection,$select_sale);
          while($sale_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_sale_query)) { ?>
          ['<?php echo $sale_result["date_format(order_date,'%M')"] ?>','<?php echo $sale_result["sum(order_total_amount)"] ?>'],
        <?php } ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {}
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Credits**: [answer to: Display item in legend even if value = 0 with
> Google Charts Tools Pie Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422273/12511801)

---

You have to add `February` - *and the other months you might not receive data* - with `0` value by default, then, modify your graph settings with this property:

```
sliceVisibilityThreshold:0
```

This is a [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/christianstorb/ozmta3nz/) modified for show the `TOSCA` with `0` value.

Code:

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
  'packages': ['corechart'],
  'callback': render
});

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function render() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2],
    ['TOSCA', 0] // This is the "February" in your case.
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {
    'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
    'width': 400,
    'height': 300,
    'sliceVisibilityThreshold': 0 // show 0 values in the graph.
  };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<h2>
  Google Pie Chart - sample with 0 value:
</h2>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```